# How to set a default value of a variable to another one in the same annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I'm searching for a way to set the default value of a variable in an annotation to another variable in the same annotation, here is what I want to do:

```
public @interface Command {
    String commandName();
    String triggerName() default commandName();
    String description() default "";
}
```

By doing this, I'm getting an error with Eclipse, which is :

```
The value for annotation attribute Command.triggerName must be a constant expression
```

So I'm not entirely sure to understand it, maybe it's asking me to change "commandName" to a constant variable (with final), but I only can put public and abstract.

Is there a way to do what I'm explaining ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, because as indicated defaults must be compile-time constants. The closest you can do is [what Spring 4.3 does](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html), implement the logic in your reader code (such as an annotation processor or runtime reflection) and document it.